# I cannot connect to the database using Play Framework 2.1.1

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server database, but the console shows

> Driver not found: [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver].

Here's the code from my Application.conf:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://test:2433;DatabaseName=Treinamento"
db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user=user
db.default.password="pwrd"
```

I added the jtds lib to the Jars folder of my project.

Comment: See this post here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839836/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-db-in-play-framework/25474256#25474256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the dependency in your Build.scala and run play update

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put the jar files in a lib folder.

```
your-project/lib/the-jar-file.jar
```

It means that the lib folder is a sibbling to the app, conf, public folder (and more).

The play application will find all jars. You will have to eclipsify or ideafy your project again.

```
play eclipse
play idea
```