# Cannot connect to Postgresql DB in Play framework

Tags: postgresql, playframework-2.0

Im trying to connect to the Postgresql using play frame work. I tried Everything but I still cant solve this problem

```
db.default.user=user
db.default.password=qwerty
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/paperclips"
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
```

but I get following error: Cannot connect to database [default]

```
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.Message:Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
[error] application - 

! @6hmjgfh72 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:92) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:570) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:252) ~[play-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:243) ~[play-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
```

Comment: "*Connection refused*" means your Postgres serer is either not running, or on a different port, or a firewall is blocking the connection

Comment: thank you, Im new to this. How do you set up Postgres server as a localhost. Im just following a Manning book Play for Scala?

Comment: Is PostgreSQL *installed* locally? What operating system/version?

Comment: I Resolved it now by installing PostgreSQL locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file **application.conf**:

```
 db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dataBaseName"
 db.default.user=user
 db.default.password="password"
```

create the path **/lib** in your main project (/) and should add the **.jar** do postgresql.

Download [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22), and after reload the project.

Or then add this code in **build.sbt**:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.2-1003-jdbc4",
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```