# Play Framework connecting to database

Tags: mysql, database, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have been following the Typesafe online training for the Play Framework (I'm a complete beginner in terms of web design), and everything was working until the part where we are supposed to connect to a database.

When I reach the second video on lesson two this site:
https://typesafe.com/how/online-training/play-java

I run into a problem, and this is the error message I get when I try refreshing my browser:

```
Cannot connect to database [default]
In /Users/Arash/playconf/conf/application.conf at line 43.
40 db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
41
 # Here we add the database that we have created locally
43 db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playconf"
44
45 # We set this to root, we login as root with no password
46 db.default.user=root
```

This is the error message in my terminal (running play)

> [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial
>   connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0.
>   Exception: null.Message:Unknown database 'playconf' [error]
>   application -
>
> ! @6hmk31f56 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
>
> play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to
>   database [default]]   at
>   play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:92)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]    at
>   play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:570)
>   ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]    at
>   play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:252)
>   ~[play-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.2]   at
>   play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:243)
>   ~[play-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.2]   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na]   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:na] Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   database 'playconf'   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0]   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>   ~[na:1.8.0]   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar:na]

I have followed everything as precisely as I can, but I get this error, and I have been stuck here all day. Very frustrating...

Then I thought, oh, maybe I don't have mysql? So I installed mysql using homebrew, and tried again, but got the same error.

Here is my code that has to do with the database:

in the config file:

```
# We add our sql driver, which we have added in the build.sbt file
 # db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver # This is the original, commented out originally
 db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

 # Here we add the database that we have created locally
 db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playconf"

 # We set this to root, we login as root with no password
 db.default.user=root
```

in the build file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaEbean,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.26",
    "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.0",
    "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1")
```

Ok, so it seemed I had to create the database, and now I have done so, but I can't access the database. I get ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'playconf'

Comment: Look at the last line, most of the issue is solved, but I can't access the database...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839836/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-db-in-play-framework/25474256#25474256

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create this `playconf` database in your MySQL server manually using for an example common DB GUI (it's NOT created automatically like ie. in H2)

After doing this kill the running app and run it again.

Comment: Thanks, this was not explained in the video, I assumed that the database was created by the code. Great, spent 7 hours figuring something as simple as this...

Comment: Well I don't know the tutorial, but it's DB's (not Play's) job - just H2 creates new DB when trying to connect, and MySQL doesn't, if this solved your problem mark the answer as correct one

Comment: @biesior I am trying to use the oauth2 in "https://github.com/nulab/scala-oauth2-provider". But in the github, they have used postgresql database. But I want to use it in the MYSQL. When I change the dependencies to "mysql"       % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18" and jdbc, I got the above error mentioned in this issue even I created table in mysql manually. Please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Test connection to the database first : 
It seems that the schema does not exists or your user doesn't have access to it !

Try this and post the output

```
 mysql -uroot -p <passwrd> -e 'use playconf;
```

Comment: When I type this command, the output is simply: > (and I can type anything after)

Comment: did you write your root password

Answer (score 0):

**application.conf**

db.default.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

db.default.url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname"

db.default.user = root

db.default.password = 12345

db.default.host = localhost

*No need to use double quotes for user,password,host and driver fields.*

**built.sbt**

*add mysql connector.*

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  filters,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
)